# how to know when connection restored in offline hybrid-remote app

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, javascript-remoting, hybrid-remote

I have a hybrid-remote app that's using javascript remoting and offline storage using SmartStore. I had considered using SmartSync or StoreCache to make my life easier but its my understanding they use the forceTK library and the API. In my case I really don't need that since I'm using javascript remoting. Is that understanding correct?

What I would like to do however is know when the connection is restored so I can call my @remoteAction method to sync/save the updates. Is there a way to register a callback or setup a listener to know when the internet connection is restored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's actually no need to detect a HTML5 event by yourself. If you are building a hybrid app (as you mentioned) using the Force.com Mobile SDK, you can directly use the Cordova offline and online listeners. The Mobile SDK uses Cordova internally so all methods are available.

Detailed info is available [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline)

Relevant code/events

```
document.addEventListener("online", yourCallbackFunction, false); Details
```

...

```
function onOnline() {     // Handle the online event }
```

Similarly for offline

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false); Details
```

...

```
function onOffline() {     // Handle the offline event }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new HTML 5 event to detect connectivity. See http://html5demos.com/offline for demo and source.

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about this, my only question is how could I hook into this to fire my sync once connection is restored? Hopefully something cleaner than just checking on a given interval.

Comment: @PhilB It's not an interval: your script will receive an event when connectivity is toggled, much like a mouse click or a key event. There's no monitoring involved. The initial check is to see if you're online during load (because you could be loaded from the cache without connectivity).